# Sticking the status bar to the root view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios7, statusbar

I am using a kind of a side menu and I want the status bar to be sticked to the root view controller *`UINavigationController`* when I am viewing the side menu, or not to cover the side menu to be more specific, I have seen apps that do that but I did not manage to do it. To clarify more:

**What it already is:**

[image: already]

**What I want to do:**

[image: desired]